# Is it possible to pass intent by intent ?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my activity I add to it some stuff by checking checkbox and if 
    `list.size()>0` shows up button which is redirecting me to second activity. In second activity I display list, when I click on it i delete object from list. Ive made button in second activity which make this `list.clear(); finish();` When I return to first activity i've still visible button. How to solve it ?

Comment: you hv to set the state of that particular event in shared pref

Comment: Like @Monica said, try using SharedPreference

Comment: @Monika It will be too much if I ask for example ?

Comment: @user3299430 i can provide that but i think i sould suggest you code according to ur req , plz post ur code and explain in  details so that i can provide you the use of shared pref

Comment: @Monika,what are you thinking about Zaied proposition ? I think it is easier but i'm beginner so i am probably wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

you must read your 'list' at activity onResume() method: when you return to your activity, onStart() is not called since it was not killed by the system

see the entire cycle in [this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Comment: could you give me an exaple,please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Gson to pass by intent any object of the class that has already been defined (not by you) and is not Serializable. Just for convenience, if you would like to pass an object of some class created by you, the class should extend `Serializable`